# How to add the properties tab to a class library project in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-standard-2.0

I have a `Visual Studio 2019` solution which has several `Class Library` projects targeting `.NET Standard 2`. Every one of these projects has a properties tab like the one described in the below image:

[image: Properties tab]

Inside the properties tab, there are several files (for example an assembly information class and resources files)

**Problem:**

I added a new `Class Library` project to the solution. I then noticed that the properties tab doesn't exist and I can't find a way to add it.

How can I add the properties tab to the newly created project in order to be coherent with the rest of the solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create the "Properties" folder and ... smile!

Answer (score 1):

You can add ItemGroup tags in your csproj file, use `AssemblyAttribute` for assembly information and `EmbeddedResource` for resource files.